# Changing the fill of mosaic plot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)
library(ggmosaic)

#Loading data
Category <- c("Bankpass", "Bankpass", "Bankpass", "Moving", "Moving")
Subcategory <- c("Stolen", "Lost", "Login", "Address", "New contract")
Weight <- c(10,20,13,40,20)
Duration <- as.character(c(0.2,0.4,0.5,0.44,0.66))
Silence <- as.character(c(0.1,0.3,0.25,0.74,0.26))
df <- data.frame(Category, Subcategory, Weight, Duration, Silence)

ui <- fluidPage(


  tags$div(class="header",
      selectInput("measure", "", c("Duration", "Silence"))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    tags$div(class = "dashboard_main",
             tags$div(class="dashboard_main_left", plotOutput("secondPlot"))

    )
  )

)
server <- function(input, output){

  output$secondPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df) +
      geom_mosaic(aes(weight = Weight, x = product(Category), fill=Duration), 
                  offset = 0, na.rm=TRUE) +  
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-25, hjust= .1)) +
      theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#e8f5e9", "#c8e6c9", "#a5d6a7", "#81c784", "#66bb6a"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server= server)
```

I would like to make the second plot interactive now. So if you select the Duration the fill in the plot "secondPlot" should be Duration and if you you select "Silence" the fill should be "Silence".

However when I change the relevante code of the graph to:

```
 ggplot(data = df) +
      geom_mosaic(aes(weight = Weight, x = product(Category), fill=input$measure), 
                  offset = 0, na.rm=TRUE) +  
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-25, hjust= .1)) +
      theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

I dont see the colour gradients anymore. Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `aes_string` inside `geom_mosaic`. Try this:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  df$prodcat <- product(df$Category)
  output$secondPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df) +
      geom_mosaic(aes_string(weight = "Weight", x = "prodcat", fill=input$measure), 
                  offset = 0, na.rm=TRUE) +  
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-25, hjust= .1)) +
      theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#e8f5e9", "#c8e6c9", "#a5d6a7", "#81c784", "#66bb6a"))
  })
}
```